# Definition of smoothness "up to boundary"

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and let $f\in\mathcal{C}^k(U)$ for some positive integer $k$.

Are the following definitions of $\mathcal{C}^k$ regularity "up to boundary" equivalent?

(1) There exists an open set $V$ containing $U$ and a $\mathcal{C}^k$ extension of $f$ to $V$.

(2) $D^{\alpha}f$ is uniformly continuous on every bounded subset of $U$ for each $|\alpha|\leq k$.

I have always interpreted the class $\mathcal{C}^k\left(\overline{U}\right)$ using definition (1) but Evans-PDE uses definition  (2) in its appendix (at least in the edition I am working from).

I can easily show that (1)$\Rightarrow$(2) but it would be nice to know if Evans definition is more general than mine.

[image]

Comment: You incorrectly cite L. Evans: see [p. 618](http://rapidshare.com/files/3469977502/p.618.docx). In fact, L. Evans wrote "$C(\overline{U})= \{ u \in C(U) | u  \text{uniformly continuous} \}$".

Comment: I did write (2) incorrectly initially in that I forgot the obvious differentiation, but the version of Evans that I have in front of me does indeed only quantify over bounded subsets (which makes sense to me, the function $x^2$ on $(0,\infty)$ should surely be considered continuous up to its boundary for instance.)

Comment: @ Sean Gomes : Could you present this in SE as a picture (I did that.)?

Comment: Image of page is now included, if that is what you were asking for.

Comment: @ Sean Gomez: Because this place was changed in the second edition, I think that (2) does not imply (1). A slight modification of your example $u(x):=(1-x)^{-2}$ on $[0,1)$ is an obvious example. It's only those who do nothing that make no mistakes.

Comment: The definition "$C(\overline{U})= \{ u \in C(U) | u  \text{uniformly continuous} \}$" from the second edition is not equivalent to (1) too: this exludes the function $f(x,y):=x^2+y^2$ defined on $\{(x,y): x \in \mathbb{R} ,y \in (-1,1) \}.$

Comment: What is $(1-x)^{-2}$ an example of? I don't see how it is an element of $\mathcal{C}(\bar{U})$ no matter which of the three definitions we take.

And yes, I agree that the definition you supplied is certainly  not equivalent to the one in my book, although I think the one  in my book is what it should be. $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ not being considered continuous up to the boundary of the domain you provided seems rather unlikely.

Regarding versioning, my book is a reprint for distribution in India, so has minor differences to the Western reprints.

Comment: Probably those spaces in question are considered only on open bounded domains $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. If $U$ is unbounded, you have to consider the more general definition given by yourself in $(2)$.

Comment: I agree Tomás. Anyway, the question still remains about whether or not (2)$\Rightarrow$ (1), as a counterexample seems elusive to me. (The claim is certainly true in the $k=0$ case as the uniform continuity (even just on bounded subsets) allows us to prove existence and uniqueness of a continuous extension to the closure $\bar{U}$, which then extends further by Tietze's extension theorem for instance.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent using a differentiable version of the Tietze extension theorem: [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-8/issue-1/Extension-of-the-range-of-a-differentiable-function/10.1215/S0012-7094-41-00812-8.short)

Comment: It seems that this link is not working anymore. Could you provide some other reference for this theorem ?