# Smooth function touching an upper semicontinuous one from above at a maximum point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set. Let $u$ be an upper semicontinuous function on $\bar \Omega$ such that $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ with a global maximum point at $\bar x$.

How can one find a function $u_\epsilon \in C^\infty(\bar \Omega)$ such that the following holds?

- $\bar x$ is a global maximum point of $u_\epsilon$,
- $u(\bar x) = u_\epsilon(\bar x)$,
- $u_\epsilon \ge u$ for every $x \in \bar \Omega$,

---

In the answer below, the inf/sup-convolution is proposed. Is the result really smooth?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Take $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $u(x) := \sqrt{x} \, (1-x)$. Then, you cannot find $v \in C^\infty(\bar\Omega)$ with $v \ge u$ and $v(0) = u(0)$.

Comment: @gerw Why do you think not?

Comment: Because $v$ cannot be differentiable in $0$. The difference quotient will diverge.

Comment: @gerw It only needs to be differentiable in the interior. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421627/definition-of-smoothness-up-to-boundary

Comment: the answer to this question says  that both notions are equivalent. Otherwise, you are invited to construct such a $v$.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer was posted before OP edited their question changing the requirements of a solution.**

If you rephrase everything in terms of lower semicontinuity and minimums you can use the Moreau Envelope (also called the Yosida regularization) and get something close to what you need.

edit: with your assumptions we have that the function $-u$ is lower semicontinuous on $\bar{\Omega}$ with $-u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and a global minimum at $\bar{x}$. Consider the function:
$$
(-u)^{(\beta)}(x) = \inf\limits_{y}\left\{-u(y) + \frac{1}{2\beta}\|x-y\|^2\right\}
$$

Then, $\bar{x}$ is a global minimum of $(-u)^{(\beta)}$, $(-u)^{(\beta)}\leq (-u)$ for all $x\in\bar{\Omega}$ and $(-u)^{(\beta)}(\bar{x})=-u(\bar{x})$.

Comment: Well now that you added the last part about the norm it's no longer true...

Comment: Are you sure that this regularization is really smooth?

Comment: Now that you mention it, if the function $u$ is not concave (i.e. $-u$ is not convex) then there could be issue. However, if $u$ is concave I can assure you that it is not only smooth but Lipschitz smooth (i.e. it has gradient that is Lipschitz continuous) with parameter $\beta$.

Comment: Is it also twice differentiable if $u$ is concave? What can be done in the general case?

Comment: Twice differentiable, no not necessarily even if we assume $u$ is concave. Here is a good answer discussing more or less this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310147/reference-request-differentiability-of-moreau-envelope

Now, if $u$ is not even concave then we are not even guaranteed differentiability. See the first figure in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.06623.pdf

They apply the envelope to a nonconvex function and the resulting function is, unfortunately, nonsmooth.

Comment: I see now that there was a miscommunication on my part because in my field it is common to call a differentiable function smooth while you were actually looking for some in $C^\infty$.

Comment: That's very unfortunate. Do you have any other ideas to address the question in the post?

Comment: I do not. Can I ask how you came across this question? i.e. what field or textbook you are studying?